# Restore-SPSite : Version string portion was too short or too long

Tags: sharepoint, restore, sharepoint-2016, sitecollection

I'm new to SharePoint.
I get this error when try to restore a backup in SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016
After I execute below command, this error is shown and the site collection "ACC" is deleted

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http://uat-intranet-sp/sites/ACC/ -path C:\temp\intra-back\ACC_20180913.bak -force




Restore-SPSite : Version string portion was too short or too long.
```

At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-SPSite http://uat-intranet-sp/sites/ACC/ -path C:\temp\intra- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:SPCmdletRestoreSite) [Restore-SPSite], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreSite

[capture screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMJkQ.png)

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version (or CU) of the SharePoint of the backed up site is different from that of the SharePoint you are trying to restore to

Comment: yup, i upgrade by Attach and Restore Content DB then use Mount command

Comment: Could you please share those commands?